# Adding serialport and usb in NestJS?

Tags: npm, package, serial-port, usb, nestjs

Is it possible to add a serial port and USB package in NestJS? I can't seem to find anything regarding these things.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your serial.module.ts, create your custom serial handler service by custom factory providers

```
import { SerialHandlerService } from './serial-handler.service';
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SerialHandlerService',
      useFactory: SerialHandlerService,
    },
  ],
})
    export class SerialModule {}
```

2. Create serial-handler.service.ts in same folder

```
import * as SerialPort from 'serialport';
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;

export const SerialHandlerService = () => {
  const port = new SerialPort(
    {YOUR_SERIAL_PORT},
    {
      baudRate: {YOUR_SERIAL_BOADRATE},
      dataBits: {YOUR_SERIAL_DATABITS},
      stopBits: {YOUR_SERIAL_STOPBITS},
      parity: {YOUR_SERIAL_PARITY},
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        // Handle Error
      }
      console.log('success')
    },
  );
  // I'm using Readline parser here. But, You can change parser that you want!
  const parser = new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' });
  port.pipe(parser);

  port.on('open', () => {
    console.info('port opened');
  });

  parser.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    // Data is string, process your data below!
  }
}
```

3. Add your serial.module.ts in your app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    // your other modules...
    SerialModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Reference: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory]

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine.